# Revert files with only keywords changed in Perforce

Tags: perforce, revert, version-control-keywords

Is it possible to automatically revert a file in Perforce if there are only keyword changes?
"p4 revert -a" will revert only those file that do not have any diff, but is it actually possible to revert if diff is similar to:

```
< @version $Id: //mydepo/myfile#1 $
> @version $Id: //mydepo/myfile#2 $
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I found a solution in a custom diff:
http://pesche.schlau.ch/2007/07/03/merge-down-copy-up/

Answer (score 0):

What does 'p4 filelog //mydepo/myfile' say?

It sounds like you submitted a second revision with no changes (other than the $Id$ expansion is different since it's a new revision). Are you saying that 'revert -a' didn't revert this otherwise-empty change?

You might want to look into the "revertunchanged" option on the workspace definition to avoid this in the future.

Comment: p4 filelog returns expected history:
    //mydepo/myfile
       ... #2 change ... edit
       ... #1 change ... add

Tried to reproduce:
1) updated workspace to "revert unchanged files"
2) opened myfile for edit and changed $Id $
3) p4 revert -a (not reverting)
4) p4 submit (submitted)

Comment: Why did you change the $Id$ in step (2)? The $Id$ is managed by the Perforce server, not by you.

Comment: That was a test. I was trying to reproduce scenario from the question.
Here it where the question came from: I don't edit "myfile" file directly, instead it's being generated (.js file from .coffee one) and the "$Id $" line is always updated from ".coffee" file.
Then Perforce, of course, changes it back, but only after the file is submitted, even when Id change is the only change